# Gap in line when trying to join up frames

Tags: vb6, grid, frames, clipping

I am trying to join several frames together to achieve a grid type arrangement:

[image]

On the left hand side there is a gap in the frame lines.  How can I get this line to join up with the frame below?

Comment: could you please post your code ?

Comment: @Hrqls: this is just in the designer.

Comment: ah i see ... you can play a but with right clicking the frames and 'bring to front' and 'send to back' .. as a general rule put the ones on the bottom to the back (as there is a small area above the frame's line) and the top ones to the front

Comment: @Hrqls: if I bring the top frame to the front then the bottom frame caption is not visible.

Comment: hmm ... the caption is a problem .. the area of the caption overlaps with the line .. without a caption you can let the top one overlap the bottom one

Comment: @Hrqls: but I want the caption to indicate what is in the frame below

Comment: some alternative ways : don't use frames but draw lines (ugly), or don't let the frames overlap show them as tiles (see example below) (default way), or don't use captions, but use a label inside the frame to show what's inside it

Comment: Or don't use the frames to provide the captions, but instead place a label with a transparent background in the appropriate position?

Answer (score 1):

as said in my comments to the original post, you can solve this by chosing the 'bring to front' and 'send to back' carefully .... that doesnt work though when you want the frames to have some captions

in code you can do the same using zorder :

```
' 1 form with :
'    1 frame : name=Frame1    index=0
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Frame1(0).Caption = ""
  For intIndex = 1 To 8
    Load Frame1(intIndex)
    Frame1(intIndex).Visible = True
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
'  PlaceNormal
'  PlaceOverlap 0
  PlaceOverlap 1
End Sub

Private Sub PlaceNormal()
  Dim intRow As Integer, intCol As Integer
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth / 3
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight / 3
  For intRow = 0 To 2
    For intCol = 0 To 2
      Frame1(intRow * 3 + intCol).Move intCol * sngWidth, intRow * sngHeight, sngWidth, sngHeight
    Next intCol
  Next intRow
End Sub

Private Sub PlaceOverlap(intOrder As Integer)
  Dim intRow As Integer, intCol As Integer
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth / 3
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight / 3 + 120
  For intRow = 0 To 2
    For intCol = 0 To 2
      Frame1(intRow * 3 + intCol).Move intCol * sngWidth, intRow * (sngHeight - 120), sngWidth, sngHeight
      Frame1(intRow * 3 + intCol).ZOrder intOrder
    Next intCol
  Next intRow
End Sub
```

but again : this doesn't work when the frames need to have some caption

Comment: +1 I think the frame captions are the root cause of the problem here

Answer (score 1):

a rough example with labels instead of frame captions

```
' 1 form with :
'    1 frame : name=Frame1    index=0
'    1 label in Frame1 : name=Label1    index=0
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Frame1(0).Caption = ""
  Label1(0).Caption = "0"
  Label1(0).Alignment = vbCenter
  For intIndex = 1 To 8
    Load Frame1(intIndex)
    Frame1(intIndex).Visible = True
    Load Label1(intIndex)
    Label1(intIndex).Visible = True
    Label1(intIndex).Caption = CStr(intIndex)
    Set Label1(intIndex).Container = Frame1(intIndex)
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  PlaceOverlap 1
End Sub

Private Sub PlaceOverlap(intOrder As Integer)
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim intRow As Integer, intCol As Integer
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth / 3
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight / 3 + 120
  For intRow = 0 To 2
    For intCol = 0 To 2
      intIndex = intRow * 3 + intCol
      With Frame1(intIndex)
        .Move intCol * sngWidth, intRow * (sngHeight - 120) - 120, sngWidth, sngHeight
        Label1(intIndex).Move 120, 120, .Width - 240, 195
        .ZOrder intOrder
      End With 'Frame1(intIndex)
    Next intCol
  Next intRow
End Sub
```